# Sending HTML Form Data to Spring REST Web Service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I am trying to send a simple String from a HTML form to my REST Web service based on spring, but even after numerous attempts I am unable to send the data to my webservice, every time I get "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect" (400) error. Can someone please look into the code snippet and let me know what I am missing out?

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/SpringRest/rest/store/prolist" method="GET">
    <p>
        Products : <input type="text" name="listofproducts"  id = "listofproducts"/>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Get the Lowest Price" />
</form>
```

Code in Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "http://localhost:8080/SpringRest/rest/store/prolist/{listofproducts}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getListOfProducts(@PathVariable String listofproducts) {
    return listofproducts;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using GET to send form data, you'll have to receive it as a request parameter not path variable because the form data is sent to the server as a request param in following format

```
http://host_port_and_url?name1=value1&name2=value2&more_params
```

So do this instead

```
@RequestMapping(value = "http://localhost:8080/SpringRest/rest/store/prolist", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getListOfProducts(@RequestParam(value = "listofproducts") String listofproducts) {
    return listofproducts;
}
```

You can check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) out

> Notes on GET:
>
> ```
> Appends form-data into the URL in name/value pairs
> The length of a URL is limited (about 3000 characters)
> Never use GET to send sensitive data! (will be visible in the URL)
> Useful for form submissions where a user want to bookmark the result
> GET is better for non-secure data, like query strings in Google
> ```

And also you don't need absolute URI mapping with host, port etc. Just use controller mapping. Assuming `store` is controller context path, this will suffice

```
@RequestMapping(value = "store/prolist", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```