# How do we pass an object from view to controller in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

Controller 1:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/allEmployees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllEmployees(@ModelAttribute("employeeListForm") EmployeeListForm employeeListForm, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model, BindingResult errors) throws Exception {
    List<Employee> subList = null;
    allEmployees = empService.getAllEmployees(categoryId);      
    employeeListForm.setAllEmployees("allEmployees");           
    employeeListForm.setCategory("IT");         
    model.addAttribute("etcSearchForm", etcSearchForm); 
    return ALL_EMP_VIEW;
}
```

Controller 2:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/EmployeeDetail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEmpDetail((@ModelAttribute("empDetailForm") EmployeeDetailForm empDetailForm, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model, BindingResult errors) throws Exception {

/*there is no direct approach to get the employee by id how                    should I get the 
  employee object from list page to deatil page 
*/
    empDetailForm.setSalary(emp.getSalary());
    empDetailForm.setTitle(emp.getTitle());
    empDetailForm.setName(emp.getName());
    model.addAttribute("empDetailForm", empDetailForm); 
    return ALL_EMP_Detail_Form;
}
```

View:

```
<div th:if="${allEmplListForm.aAllEmployees.size() > 0}" th:each="emp : ${allEmplListForm.aAllEmployees}" th:object="${emp}" >                           
    <a th:href="@{/EmployeeDetail)}" class="link">
        <div><p class="name" th:text="*{name}"></p></div>
        <div><p th:text="*{date}"></p> <p th:text="*{title}"></p></div>
        <div><p class="salary" th:text="*{salary}"></p></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I am displaying list of employees in one page and when I click on the employee it has to take me to the detail page(controller 2) where there is no direct service method to get employee by id or name or some other.

How should I send my employee object from view to controller. Clicking on the link it should take to the detail page.

Comment: How are you listing them; can you show the code for that?

Comment: I think you need to add more information..but if you need to pass something from view to controller than it will be an AJAX call.

Comment: Why don't you write a service method, then on list page on clicking the employee row yo can get employee detail by Id or name. E. G. /emp/(id)  get request.

Comment: We dont have direct method in our dao to find employee by emp id,

Answer (score 0):

Your question is like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669212/send-datas-from-html-to-controller-in-thymeleaf) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926136/spring-and-thymeleaf-sending-an-object-to-a-controller-from-a-theach-table). I think there is no other option than make `<form>` element and post the Employee object to the controller.

Comment: I think second one closer to mine, but I dont want to use POST(i just need GET with employee object)  inorder to go into the detail page.

Comment: You can send `<form>` using GET method. [Here an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640084/sending-html-form-data-to-spring-rest-web-service)